# What is this SE's attitude towards Christianity?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this an SE *about* Christianity, or is this a Christian SE? That is, is this a SE for asking what positions are held within Christianity, or is it an SE in which the truth of Christianity is assumed, and answers are written taking that as given? How much leeway is there for expressing disrespect for non-Christians? For instance, is it acceptable to refer to positions one disagrees with as "heresy", "blasphemy", "idolatry", etc.? Is it acceptable to refer to non-Christians as "rejecting the truth"?

In response to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79917/why-do-most-christians-eat-pork-when-deuteronomy-says-not-to), one answer refers to non-Jews as following "[false gods](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/79920/41350)", and another answer calls homosexuality an "[abomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/79971/41350)". How is the Code of Conduct interpreted in reference to these sort of statements?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/79971/41350) is clearly quoting something. It's not talking about homosexuality, it's talking about a hermenuitic, making a distinction inside the text of the Bible.

So it's talking *about* Christianity, not casting aspersions on homosexuals.

---

The other one is not even remotely calling Jews following false Gods, if anything it's calling everyone except Jews as sacrificing to false Gods (at least that's what the Bible says).

---

That question should be closed FWIW, it's a total dupe.  There's about 9000 questions about why Christians don't do things in the OT.

Comment: With the first, "There are statements of truth. I'll leave it to the reader to find those, but one example is regarding homosexuality". One could interpret "statement of truth" as meaning "statement about truth", but that's a stretch. On the second point, you seem to have missed the "non-" before "Jews": "one answer refers to non-Jews as following "false gods" "

Answer (score 1):

> That is, is this a SE for asking what positions are held within Christianity, or is it an SE in which the truth of Christianity is assumed, and answers are written taking that as given?

Officially the first, but I don't think it makes as much difference as you think it might.

> How much leeway is there for expressing disrespect for non-Christians? For instance, is it acceptable to refer to positions one disagrees with as "heresy", "blasphemy", "idolatry", etc.? Is it acceptable to refer to non-Christians as "rejecting the truth"?

We definitely want all answers to be respectful to all. But being respectful does not preclude saying that one Christian group considers another to be heretics, blasphemous, or idolatrous. Similarly Christian theology may say that other religions are wrong, evil, denials of the truth, etc.

If this feels a little nebulous, then apologies. I think we do a generally good job at removing rude, disrespectful, or abusive content. If you see something you think doesn't belong, please flag it. If your flag gets declined then you can write a new Meta post discussing it and explaining why you think it is problematic, and we can deal with it case by case.